# on a CV do you list both a paper and an associated oral presentation?

Tags: cv, presentation

I attended a conference that accepts short papers as well as accepts the papers for oral or poster presentations.  I had four papers, for two of which I gave the oral presentations.  My conundrum is that on my CV do I list both the papers as well as the associated presentations or just the papers as that is in some sense the higher priority?

Answer (score 1):

I generally see people break their CV into peer-reviewed and non-peer reviewed contributions. Then within those categories they indicate whether or not they were the presenting author.

The presentation is really presenting the work in your paper, so they are one and the same. Plus consider the fact that the proceedings of the conference are what people will be able to find your work in, and therefore you want to give them the information for your paper. For example:

> **Peer Reviewed Contributions**
>
> Your Name, Co-Author, Co-Author, "A breakthrough in a big question", *The International Journal of Great Answers*, vol. 42, no. 0, pp. 3141-5926.
>
> etc...
>
> **Non-Peer Reviewed Contributions**
>
> '*' Co-Author, Your Name Co-Author, "A very novel and important answer to a very big question", *The 9th World Conference of Very Big Questions*, Conference paper and presentation.
>
> Your Name, Co-Author, Co-Author, "The smallest possible answer to the biggest possible question", *The 42nd World Conference of Very Small Answers*, Conference paper and poster presentation.
>
> Note: Contributions with an asterisk '*' indicate that Your Name was the presenting author.